# MFMessageComposeViewController and iMessage

Tags: ios5, sms

I'm building an app that has a button. If you touch that button, an `MFMessageComposeViewController` will show, with the body filled in and one recipient. This recipient is '4343', a shortcode for texting in Belgium.

The wrong thing here is that the `MFMessageComposeViewController` will setup everything as an iMessage: the 'send' button is blue and the recipient is formatted as '(434) 3' and is also colored in blue.

Shortly, this means that iOS chooses for iMessage, but i want to override that. Does anyone know how I can override this behavior and make it send real text messages (SMS).

What I can see is that if the text is sent, it appears as a normal text in my Messages app. But this is still confusing...

Comment: It appears that `MFMessageComposeViewController` is currently broken: it will only work if _all_ recipients are registered with iMessage. That is, it forces iMessage, unlike the Messages app. It's a bug. Please report it.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the [MFMessageComposeViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html), there’s no public way to do this.

If you type `4343` into the regular Messages app, does it also highlight it in blue?
(I realise this question is months old…)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that the MFMessageComposeViewController only displays a blue 'send' button in any case. So as a user you can't see whether it's sending an iMessage, an SMS (because of the receiver not being registered to iMessage) or even a MMS (when sending text to a Mail-address or sending something like a contact from Contacts.app or a photo or something else which is not text-only).

Comment: This is not actually true. See my comment to the question.

Comment: No, my tests have shown that `MFMessageComposeViewController` will actually send a SMS if the receiver is not registered to iMessage. It will just not show a green button if that's the case, as it would in the real Message.app.

Comment: I just tried it. It will send a standard message (SMS) to ALL recipients if one or more are not registered with iMessage. So it'll work just as Messages.app would do and not send any iMessage if one of the group is not registered.

Comment: Hmm. Not sure why it doesn't do that for me.