# iPhone SMS Url Scheme with Body Content?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sms

I am looking to pre-fill the SMS body with content given "smsto:555-555-5555:Hello World"

I have done my research and everybody says it cannot be done but I have a QR reader on my phone right now that can take "sms:555-555-5555:Hello world" and pre-fills the content with the correct phone number scanned.

So my question is. How do i do this? it is pretty clear that the URL scheme provided doesn't handle the body. What other methods are out there to pre-fill the body? it can clearly be done with the QuickMark Reader.

Comment: I Solved the problem..
if anyone is looking for the solution here is the tutorial

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/

Comment: The problem is that MFMessageComposeViewController is currently broken for non-iMessage: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8314645/974531

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modalViewController for SMS to fill the body of a text.

1. add the MessageUI framework to your project.
2. set you viewController as the MFMessageComposeDelegate
3. Create the modal view and present it:

   ```
   -(void) showMessageComposerWithText:(NSString*)messageText telNumber:(NSString*)telNumber composeDelegate:(id)delegate
   {
       MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

       if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]){   
           controller.body = messageText;
           controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:telNumber];
           controller.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;

           [delegate presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can't launch the Messages app with a predefined message according to [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1).

What you can do is implement the handling yourself and parse the URL like the following:

```
NSURL *url = /* the url you get from the web (in webview delegate) or after QR Code scan */;

if ([url.scheme isEqualToString:@"sms"]) // is it a sms ?
{
    if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]) // can I send text message ?
    {   
        NSArray *parts = [url.absoluteString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        NSString *messageText = parts.count == 3 ? [parts objectAtIndex:2] : @"";
        NSString *telNumber = parts.count >= 2 ? [parts objectAtIndex:1] : @"";
        MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.body = messageText;
        controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:telNumber];
        controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

        [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
        [controller release];
    }
}
```

And voilà !